# How to add element/s conditions in WHERE clause to a (weakly) connected components query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find a query in cypher that returns the (weakly) connected components in graph with between 20 and 30 elements and with at least of 10 elements with the property "prop"=True.

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('User', 'RELATED_WITH', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId
WITH setId,count(*) AS size,algo.getNodeById(nodeId) AS node
WHERE size >= 20 AND size <= 30 AND ???
RETURN node.id,setId
```

The code does almost what I'm looking for, that is, it looks for (weakly) connected components between 20 and 30 elements, but I don't know how to introduce the condition of the nodes in the WHERE clause (or wherever) (look the ??? signs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems you have is that `count(*)` will always be 1 as you are also aggregating by each node. Remember that Neo4j has implied grouping, where it will group by all elements in the row.

One can get the count of nodes with `prop=True` with a simple `sum(CASE WHEN ...)` statement

Solution:

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('User', 'RELATED_WITH', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId
WITH setId,algo.getNodeById(nodeId) AS node
WITH setId,count(*) as size, 
           collect(node) as nodes,
           sum(CASE WHEN node.prop = True THEN 1 ELSE 0) END as prop_true_count
WHERE size >= 20 AND size <= 30 AND prop_true_count >= 10
UNWIND nodes as n
RETURN n.id,setId
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!!